# Run the lib script before building the application in nx

Tags: typescript, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have the following structure. Other project file have omitted

```
.
├── apps
│   └── user
│       ├── project.json
├── libs
│   └── shared
│       ├── db-common
│       │   ├── project.json

50 directories, 61 files
```

The `libs/shared/db-common/project.json` file has a target script `migrations:build`

```json
{
  "name": "shared-db-common",
  ...
  "targets": {
    ...
    "migrations:build": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "rimraf dist/migrations/shared",
          "tsc -p libs/shared/db-common/tsconfig.migrations.shared.json"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

Also I have the `user` application. I want to run `nx run shared-db-common:migrations:build` before build my `user` application. How can I do it?

Comment: [Docs](https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration#targets) suggests adding `"dependsOn": ["migrations:build"]` to the target `build`. I personlly run into issues when the target name has a colon so would need to rename `"migrations-build"`

Comment: I've renamed to `migrations-build`. Neither `"dependsOn": ["^shared-db-common:migrations-build"],` nor `"dependsOn": ["shared-db-common:migrations-build"],` nor `"dependsOn": ["migrations-build"],` don't not work